# Kleinberg model in nw extension is wrong?

Tags: graph, netlogo

I tried to generate a graph using the Kleinberg model in the nw extension:

```
nw:generate-small-world turtles links 4 4 2 false
```

Then I sorted all the nodes according to their ID property ("who") in a 2D lattice:

[image]

But shouldn't the Kleinberg model generate nodes that are connected to all their 4 neighbors? maybe the nodes ID are in random order? or I'm getting the Kleinberg model wrong?

Comment: see also https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kleinberg model is working as it should. The behavior you observe is due to the random order that the turtles make links with other turtles. In Netlogo, the turtles will perform functions in random order. You can specify creating ordered agentsets, but expect the IDs ("who") to be in random order by default. You can type the two commands below in the Command Center for an easy and relevant demonstration of this after generating the Kleinberg network:

```
 ask turtles [show who]
 ask turtles [show [who] of link-neighbors]
```

These will return output like this:

```
observer> ask turtles [show who]
(turtle 0): 0
(turtle 5): 5
(turtle 9): 9
(turtle 2): 2
(turtle 12): 12
(turtle 14): 14
(turtle 10): 10
(turtle 15): 15
(turtle 4): 4
(turtle 13): 13
(turtle 3): 3
(turtle 7): 7
(turtle 6): 6
(turtle 1): 1
(turtle 8): 8
(turtle 11): 11
observer>  ask turtles [show [who] of link-neighbors]
(turtle 9): [13 7 14 1]
(turtle 10): [1 12 15 4 2]
(turtle 13): [2 14 8 9 11]
(turtle 15): [10 7 3 4 6 14 12]
(turtle 3): [4 12 11 8 5 15]
(turtle 14): [9 15 7 13]
(turtle 2): [4 10 13]
(turtle 6): [0 5 15]
(turtle 4): [3 12 2 10 15 5]
(turtle 7): [0 8 14 9 1 12 15]
(turtle 1): [10 9 8 11 7]
(turtle 8): [0 13 3 7 1]
(turtle 11): [0 1 3 13]
(turtle 5): [4 3 0 6]
(turtle 0): [11 8 5 6 7]
(turtle 12): [15 3 10 4 7]
```

Note the random order of the `turtles` responding to the commands, as well as the order of the `link-neighbors`